# How do i upload to amazon s3 using Heroku composer amazon aws sdk

Tags: php, heroku, amazon-web-services, heroku-toolbelt, aws-php-sdk

I'm using heroku and i'm following this tutorial here, https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3-upload-php

I have placed the composer require line in my composer.json file as shown below.

{
  "require" : {
    "silex/silex": "~1.1",
    "monolog/monolog": "~1.7"
  },
  "require-dev": {
    "heroku/heroku-buildpack-php": "*"
  },
  "require" : {
    "aws/aws-sdk-php": "~2.6"
  }
}

As you can see i placed the amazon one last. However, i'm receiving the following error message.

2015-02-27T16:26:05.499004+00:00 app[web.1]: [27-Feb-2015 16:26:05 UTC] PHP Warning:  require(vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /app/web/fb/fileupload.php on line 4

Does anyone know if i have to do anything other than place that line in my composer json file???? please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You now have two "require" keys, how is that supposed to work? It's a hash map, the keys overwrite each other!

This is what you want:

```
{
  "require": {
    "silex/silex": "~1.1",
    "monolog/monolog": "~1.7",
    "aws/aws-sdk-php": "~2.6"
  },
  "require-dev": {
    "heroku/heroku-buildpack-php": "*"
  }
}
```

And then you of course have to run `composer update` to generate a `composer.lock`, and check that into the repos along with the rest of your code.

Why don't you run the app locally on your computer before pushing it up to Heroku?

Comment: I'm sort of a newbie developer, only coding since 2009 and only with as3, php, c#, .net. The app requires the facebook graph api and i'm not exactly sure how to run the app locally. Anyways, I need to somehow run composer update on my heroku dyno

Comment: No you don't. Like I said, you run `composer update` locally, so your dependency versions are frozen to a known and reproducible state in `composer.lock`. That's the whole point of dependency management. You then check in the changed `composer.json` and  `composer.lock`, and push that to Heroku, it will install the dependencies for you.

Comment: And of course if you want to include the autoloader from inside the `fb/` subfolder of your application, then you need to `require('../vendor/autoload.php');`, or better yet, `require(__DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php');`...

Comment: why does my .gitignore file contain the vender directory? do i have to remove that so the libs get transferred to the server on my next push?

Comment: No. The `vendor/` directory contains the dependencies' source code. The whole point of Composer, Bundler, NPM etc is that you do *not* check in the dependency sources, only the "declaration", which is `composer.json` (what you "require") and `composer.lock` (a "frozen" state from when you last ran `composer update`, so you, your co-developers, Heroku etc always install the exact same dependencies on each `composer install` or deploy, and not new versions some day that break things). Just follow the instructions I gave you and Heroku will install the AWS SDK.

Answer (score 0):

So looks like an include can not find `vendor/autoload.php`

Are you sure that it exists?

`vendor` folder should be in `fb` folder an have that file. 
Remember it is case sensitive.

1. Just make sure that you point to proper file on an include.
2. Make sure you ran `composer install`

Comment: Ok, i've changed my composer json file to be like yours. How do i run heroku composer update?

Comment: when i try to run composer install using the heroku toolbelt CLI, it says command not found

Comment: also, the file doesn't exist. i gotta run composer update somehow